# ListView Delete Refresh does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, refresh

I'm developing WPF MVVM Application with the basic CRUD functionality. I use ListView that contains and show data for users. When I Add or Update some User ListVew is refreshing immediately, but after Delete command ListView is not refreshing. In that case I have to close application and run again to make refresh ListView.

## XAML

```
<ListView  Name="LstUsers" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList.View, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="150" Margin="0,40,10,260" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

## VIEW MODEL

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _users;


public UserViewModel()
{

  _users = new ObservableCollection<User>(GetAllUsers());

// Paging Control
  ViewList = new CollectionViewSource();
  ViewList.Source = Users;
  ViewList.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ViewFilter);

  CurrentPageIndex = 0;
  itemcount = Users.Count;
  CalculateTotalPages();
}

#region DeleteCommand

    public ICommand DeleteUserCmd
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(k => DeleteUser(CurrentSelectedUser)); }
    }

    // Delete user from database.
    private void DeleteUser (User user)
    {
        if(CurrentSelectedUser != null)
        {
            using (var userManager = new UserManager())
            {
                MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete user?", "Delete user?", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Asterisk);
                if (msgResult == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {
                    return;
                }
                userManager.Delete(user);
                MessageBox.Show("User is deleted!", "Confirm!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Asterisk);

                // Refresh Listview after delete record.
                Users.Remove(user);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You must select user!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);  
    }

    #endregion
```

## MODEL

```
public CollectionViewSource ViewList { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList.View, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True,ModeTwoWay}"

Comment: try this ViewList.View.Refresh(); after line OnPropertyChanged("Users");

Comment: I tried nothing happened and when I inserted Mode=TwoWay in ItemSource as your first comment I got error: A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'View' of type 'System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource'.

Comment: is your list ViewList chnaging or not after deleteting the user in code

Comment: check list with breakpoint

Comment: you should use single list to bind your ListView control

Comment: It is not changing. There are the same number of records during application running. When close application then it'is updated.

Comment: I tested with single Collection directly to bind to Users Collection and it does not work again.

Comment: if you are binding with single collection  then declare public ObservableCollection<User> Users{get;set;} and inherit class INotifyPropertyChanged in view model

Comment: and don't create new instance of users in your code except in constructor

Comment: Meer Deen if you look in my code above you can see that I have public  this collectin with INotifyPropertyChanged - OnPreprtyChanged. Instance of class exsists only in Conustructor.                                          ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }

Comment: make simple { get; set; } getter setter of observablecollection

Answer (score 1):

I added this line

```
Users.Remove(Users.Where(i => i.UserId == user.UserId).Single());
```

instead of

```
Users.Remove(user);
```

and now when I debug code after Delete Command Count Users is minus one but application failed on

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

```
public User CurrentSelectedUser
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            UserId = value.UserId;
            FirstName = value.FirstName;
            LastName = value.LastName;
            Username = value.Username;
            Password = value.Password;
            UserTypeId = value.UserTypeId;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedUser");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Was this a translation error? I notice Korisnici is bosnian for "The Users"

What is ViewList.View that you're binding your ItemsSource to?

Anyway, you're presumably binding the items to the property "Users", hence why you are calling OnPropertyChanged("Users") when you want to update your list.

However, you're removing the user from "Korisnici":

```
// Refresh Listview-a after delete record.
Korisnici.Remove(user);
OnPropertyChanged("Users");
```

Not the "Users" collection. unless Korisnici.Remove is a method you have created? What is Korisnici? I think you want:

```
// Refresh Listview-a after delete record.
Users.Remove(user);
```

Note, you don't need the OnPropertyChanged("Users") - this is managed by the ObservableCollection, which implements INotifyCollectionChanged itself to notify of changes to the collection.

Comment: Sorry for mistake. I have translated code in English so I didn't see this part with "Korisnici" . It is User's Collection. I used ViewList CollectionViewSource because I have Paging Control that uses CollectionViewSource and on this way bind to ItemSource. I use OnPropertyChanged("Users") on Update and Add method and evertything works well so that I include on the Delete command.

Comment: What happens if you update or add to the list after you've deleted a User? Does it then show the deleted User has gone?

Comment: In that case I got message "The user is updated" but in ListView didn't update fields to new values if you mean on "deleted user" ? Other records work well and after deleted ?

Comment: And a different user? (not the one deleted)

Comment: I've deleted  OnPropertyChanged("Users") and same thing.

Comment: If you drop in a breakpoint on updating a different user like you just did - does the Users collection have the original user still in it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understund your querstion well?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to check where the issue is. The issue is either with the binding/updating of the UI, or the removing of the User from the list. To check this do this:
1) Remove a User (nothing happens)
2) Plase break point in code in the "Modification" Method.
3) Modify User, so now the breakpoint is hit and you can see the properties in the debuger
4) Hover over the Users list and see if the user you removed earlier is present or not.  

If the user is present in the list in step 4, the databinding/refreshing list is working. If the not, then it's not being removed properly.

Comment: 1) I removed some user and before that I put break point in Update/Modification method. 2) I updated some fields for (removed user) and properties got these values. The Collection<Users> still contains 7 Users/Count when I make hover over collection altough in Databse has 6 record after this action.

Comment: Strange. So it seems it's not an issue with the ListBox at all, but for some reason it's never getting removed from the Users collection. Can you break at "Users.Remove(user);" and see if it gets to this line? Check the Users.Count before, then step over and see if it's changed.

Comment: The ObserveCollection<User> has the same Count after this line     Users.Remove(user) ? Remove does not work while Users.Add(user) count has changed for one.

Comment: What does the debugger say "User" is? Perhaps this could be null, so remove isn't working correctly. It could also be a copy of the original User class you're trying to delete (a new one created with the same data from the database or something?) Though it's the "CurrentUser" which is bound to the listView so I'd expect it to be correct... Strange

If you try removing using the index of the User with RemoveAt(userIndex), does that work?

Comment: Debugger shows values of properties for this removed User. They aren't null except UserTypeID field which is null and he has foreign key on the UserType class.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."? I suspect it's on this line:

```
UserId = value.UserId;
```

When you delete the selected user, the list gets updated (At last! Hurah) - when this happens the CurrentSelectedUser doesn't exist anymore (it's just got deleted) so I suspect the binding is set to null. (nothing selected).

That calls the set{} method with value=null. So value.UserId; throws the exception.

You need to handle the CurrentSelectedUser being set to null like this or similar:

```
public User CurrentSelectedUser
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            UserId = value.UserId;
            FirstName = value.FirstName;
            LastName = value.LastName;
            Username = value.Username;
            Password = value.Password;
            UserTypeId = value.UserTypeId;
        }
        else
        {
             UserId = -1;// or other "NO USER" condition
             //etc etc
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedUser");
    }
}
```

Comment: Joe Thank you very much for your help. Everything works.

Comment: @enzodev Great! No problem, glad I could help. I learnt about CollectionViewSource (never come across that before) and it's perfect for the application I'm working on.